# A mysqli update returns 1 in mysqli_stmt_affected_rows but any change in DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code that returns 1 in mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt):

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE milestone SET date = ? WHERE id = ?');
$a = 1;
$b = 110;
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $b, $a);    
$stmt->execute();
sendResponse(200, json_encode(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)));
$stmt->close();
```

But I cannot see any change in my MySQL Database! Is the correct onem no doubr about it, I even checked it in the same Aplication with a SELECT. Where is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: @Fred-ii-: nope, affected_rows uses the statement handle...`int $mysqli_stmt->affected_rows;` and `int mysqli_stmt_affected_rows ( mysqli_stmt $stmt )`. Can't use the connection handle, as there may be multiple queries outstanding which'd have affected_rows handles.

Comment: If you comment the line sendResponse(200, json_encode(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))); will your update works? if NO, I think you are trying to update the date as integer number and that might be the problem, just some thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is fairly obvious. You are passing 110 to a date field and that will not work. Date fields are normally passed a string representation of a date, or date and time.

However this does highlight the fact that you are not correctly checking the results of your queries and are just assuming they will always work.

Also it is a good idea to stick to one or other paradigm i.e. mysqli OO or Proceedural, but not to switch between both.

So I suggest you start using this method on all you database access code.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE milestone SET date = ? WHERE id = ?');
if ( ! $stmt ) {
    echo $this->db->error;
    exit;
}

$a = 1;
// pass a string representation of a date
$b = '2015-09-12';

// change the date parameter's data type to string
$stmt->bind_param("si", $b, $a);    

$status = $stmt->execute();
if ( ! $status ) {
    echo $stmt->error;
    exit;
}

sendResponse(200, json_encode($stmt->affected_rows));
```